# Why does this no longer render the "test tri"?

Tags: rendering, directx11, sharpdx

So I got this code about rendering a shaded tri using sharpDX ...

```
var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);
var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

var layout = new InputLayout(
    device,
    ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode),
    new[]
        {
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
            new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16, 0)
        });

var vertices = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[]
    {
        new Vector4(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        new Vector4(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        new Vector4(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
    });
```

As with all demos they are often not very modular and over wordy, but also I wanted to play with other ways of rendering in these simple scenarios before I move on to more complex things.

So I updated the code to this ...

```
var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("Shaders/Coloured.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None));
var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("Shaders/Coloured.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None));
VertexPositionColour[] data = new VertexPositionColour[]
{
    new VertexPositionColour { Position = new Vector4(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), Colour = new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    new VertexPositionColour { Position = new Vector4(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), Colour = new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    new VertexPositionColour { Position = new Vector4(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), Colour = new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) }
};

var vertices = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, data);
```

And now the test triangle no longer renders.
Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: I assume you didn't change the input layout declaration? I don't know about SharpDX specifically, but you should be able to create a debug version of the device by passing "D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG" to the D3D11CreateDevice function. It will [spam out errors for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff476881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Debug) which should hopefully be helpful.   Also, on an off chance that there are mode changes to the code than I can see here, or you've accidently adjusted the vertexes so your tri is backface culled, try and set your cullmode to D3D11_CULL_NONE.

Comment: Also, you're using a different FX file this time. Are VS and PS _exactly_ the same in both these files? Does your new VS remember to output SV_Position and do so in the same way as the old file?

Comment: hmmm I didn't know about creating a debug device, thanks for that ... good call !! its the same tri data and shader code literally the only code I changed was this and defined the new struct to hold a position and a colour "VertexPositionColour" I maybe replicating sharpDX toolkit behaviour here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok I didn't think I needed the input layout any more 
Changing the second example to include this ...

```
vertices = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, data);

var inputLayout = new InputLayout(
    device,
    ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode), new[]
        {
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
            new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16, 0)
        });

device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout = inputLayout;
```

... fixes the problem.

But that raises the question of why I can't do this ...

```
vertices = Buffer.Create(device, ref data, VertexPositionColour.BufferDescription);
```

It says there are some invalid args.
Hmmm DX is a strange world!

Comment: It says there are invalid arguments because there is no "Create" method that takes a "ref T[]" as the second parameter. The closest potential option takes a "T[]", which is not the same thing.